# Unable to apply tqdm to an LDA model to track training progress

Tags: progress-bar, lda, tqdm

I am currently using jupyter notebooks to run experiments in order to find the best topic model implementing the **LDA** algorithm; however I would like to have a progress bar to have an idea of the remaining training time for each experiment. I read `tqdm()` is the best option, nevertheless  I am struggling to implement this feature.

What I have tried so far is to wrap  `corpus` to pass it as the  iterable, but although it does generate a progress bar that quickly fills up to a 100%, the training continues way after the bar is completely full.
I suppose that behavior is connected to the fact that the documentation for `tqdm` always shows it is to be implemented in a for loop like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm.trange(100):
    pass
```

but I just can´t see how to reconcile that with `LdaModel()`

This is my code:

```
num_topics = 2
chunksize = 2000
passes = 20
iterations = 10
eval_every = 
random_state=100
alpha= 1 
per_word_topics=True
minimum_phi_value=0.001

#Training the model
from tqdm import tqdm

lda_model = LdaModel(
corpus=tqdm(corpus),
id2word=dictionary,
chunksize=chunksize,
alpha=alpha,
eta='auto',
minimum_probability=0.001,
iterations=iterations,
num_topics=num_topics,
passes=passes,
random_state=random_state,
per_word_topics=per_word_topics,
minimum_phi_value = minimum_phi_value,
eval_every=eval_every)

print("LDA TOPICS baby! >>>>")

#parameters for show_topics
log=True 
num_words=5
print(lda_model.show_topics(num_words=num_words,log=log ))
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 1):

In ldamodel.py (def update() around line 950 in my version), you can wrap the loop for the number of passes with tqdm. Search for for pass_ in (range(passes)), and wrap with tqdm function.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for pass_ in tqdm(range(passes)):
```